# stop background music of other app only when the video is unmuted in my app Swift UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, avplayer, avaudiosession

> applicationDidBecomeActive

```
 do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: .duckOthers)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

The audio by other app will not stop when the video is playing in my app, just reduce the volume, this is what I want

```
self.player.isMuted = true
```

video will play in mute mode,
I want to achieve that When I unmute my video, so other apps audio should stop
Like in Facebook

I try to set when mute / unmute button tapped:

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: .interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

pause spoken audio content from other sessions when app plays its audio but It does not work
even I set

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is to stop other apps' audio. If you want that default behavior, don't pass `.duckOthers`  or `.interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers`. Both of these say you **don't want to stop** other audio. So just use:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
```

Comment: But I want to achieve that, If my video is mute, background music should not stop, when I tap to unmute my video then other background music should be paused

Comment: Right, so don't activate your audio session when it's mute. Activate it when you want to pause other music.

Comment: It worked, when the user taps on a video to unmute, I set it to the playback category